# How to retrieve a GUID and value from a string in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like this in Ruby

```
word=0 id=891efc9a-2210-4beb-a19a-5e86b2f8a49f
```

How can I get both the word and id values from that string?

Comment: I didn't downvote but you should typically post some code which you have already tried in your question (and which fails for some specific reason).  Otherwise you come off as asking other people to do your work for you, without any effort on your part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that will work - split up the target string into tokens by whitespace and equals-sign characters (`tokens=str.split(/[= ]/)`) and create a Hash out of them (`Hash[*tokens]`).  The [result is a `Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) whose keys are the token before the equals sign and the values are the ones after it:

```ruby
s = 'word=0 id=891efc9a-2210-4beb-a19a-5e86b2f8a49f'
h = Hash[*s.split(/[= ]/)]
h # => {"word"=>"0", "id"=>"891efc9a-2210-4beb-a19a-5e86b2f8a49f"}
h['word'] # => "0"
h['id'] # => "891efc9a-2210-4beb-a19a-5e86b2f8a49f"
```

Of course, it will break if your "keys" or "values" contain equal signs or spaces but it works for your example.

Answer (score 1):

This should help!

```
s = "word=0 id=891efc9a-2210-4beb-a19a-5e86b2f8a49f"

data = {}

s.scan(/(\w+)(?=\=)\=([^\s]+)/).each do |pair|
  key, value = pair
  data[key.to_sym] = value
end

puts data.inspect    
#=> {"word"=>"0", "id"=>"891efc9a-2210-4beb-a19a-5e86b2f8a49f"}

puts data[:word]
#=> 0

puts data[:id]
#=> 891efc9a-2210-4beb-a19a-5e86b2f8a49f
```

Comment: I updated this to generate a hash which feels a bit more usable.

Answer (score 1):

```
string="word=0 id=891efc9a-2210-4beb-a19a-5e86b2f8a49f"

word,id = string.match(/word=(.*) id=(.*)/).captures
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something simple like:

```
str = 'word=0 id=891efc9a-2210-4beb-a19a-5e86b2f8a49f'
word, id = str.scan(/=(\S+)/).flatten # => ["0", "891efc9a-2210-4beb-a19a-5e86b2f8a49f"]
```

Each of the values you want are preceded by `=` so use that as the place-holder for the value. Using the capture `(...)` in the regular expression tells `scan` to create a new sub-array, so `flatten` will promote the sub-arrays back to standard array elements:

```
'foo'.scan(/(o)/) # => [["o"], ["o"]]
'foo'.scan(/(o)/).flatten # => ["o", "o"]
```